# Separating an array into categories - automatically

Tags: php, twig

I have a one array with items in Twig. Each item has a category key.
I would like to list items from given categories in separate lists.

I have no idea how to display all items in separate divs for a category - like this:

```
<div id="cat-1">
    items from cat 1...
</div>

<div id="cat-2">
    items from cat 2...
</div>
```

Sample array:

```
array:10 [
0 => array:2 [
    "type" => "type1"
    "object" => {
        name: "Sample name 1"
        category: "Cat1"
    }
]
1 => array:2 [
    "type" => "type1"
    "object" => {
        name: "Sample name 2"
        category: "Cat2"
    }
]
2 => array:2 [
    "type" => "type1"
    "object" => {
        name: "Sample name 3"
        category: "Cat1"
    }
]
3 => array:2 [
    "type" => "type1"
    "object" => {
        name: "Sample name 4"
        category: "Cat2"
    }
]
```

I would be grateful for any help.

**UPDATE:**
After your advice, I was able to come to the following code:

```
{% set organised_cats = [] %}
{% for element in elemementsAll %}
    {% set organised_cats = organised_cats|merge([
    [element.object.category, element]
    ]) %}

{% endfor %}
```

Array result:

```
array:10 [
    0 => array:2 [
        0 => "Cat1"
        1 => array:2 [
            "type" => "type1"
            "object" => {
                name: "Sample name 1"
                category: "Cat1"
            }
        ]
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
        0 => "Cat2"
        1 => array:2 [
            "type" => "type1"
            "object" => {
                name: "Sample name 2"
                category: "Cat2"
            }
        ]
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
        0 => "Cat1"
        1 => array:2 [
            "type" => "type1"
            "object" => {
                name: "Sample name 3"
                category: "Cat1"
            }
        ]
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
        0 => "Cat2"
        1 => array:2 [
            "type" => "type1"
            "object" => {
                name: "Sample name 4"
                category: "Cat2"
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Reorganise your input array so it is in category order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorganise your input array so it is in category order

```
$organised_cats = [];

foreach ($sample as $cat) {
    $organised_cats[ $cat['object']['category'] ] [] = $cat;
}
```

You should end up with an array like this

```
Array
(
    [Cat1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => type1
                    [object] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Sample name 1
                            [category] => Cat1
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => type1
                    [object] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Sample name 3
                            [category] => Cat1
                        )

                )

        )

    [Cat2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => type1
                    [object] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Sample name 2
                            [category] => Cat2
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => type1
                    [object] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Sample name 4
                            [category] => Cat2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Then pass that array to your twig to process

Comment: There is probably a dupe for this advice.

Comment: Based on your code, I wrote it in twig ( updated thread) - but it's probably not the same as in your example. Can I get the effect of listing by category from such an array?